# Jquery Ajax - handle paths for js/css scripts for direct and remote access

Tags: jquery, ajax

Using Jquery Ajax i have an entry script "index.php"

This script lets the user request "/folder2/index.php" via ajax.

I use the above requested path "/folder2/index.php" ***also for direct access.***

Since the ajax call makes it, as far as i know, necessary to rename the paths from 
all included js and css scripts in "/folder2/index.php" to match the path of the "index.php" **....**

**...** i am searching for a solution without cloning / moving the script or usage of absolute paths that makes the script usable for direct and remote access.

How do you handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i know use different session variables based on the source of access (direct / remote) with a conditional at the header to different paths.